# jQuery qtip2 tooltip to show on load, hide after 5 seconds and also show again on mouseenter without a delay

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I'm using jQuery Qtip2 for a clients website and they have asked that a tooltip appears on page load then disappears after 5 seconds. The same tooltip also needs to appear on mouseeenter after the first loading has closed.

I have made it so it appears on page load and also on click and mouseenter, but am unsure how to make it do both, with a timeout for the first event and no delay on the mouseenter/click event.

Any suggestions?

My code so far looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.helpful_hint').qtip({
        style: { classes: 'customHint' },
        content: {
            text: 'text here'
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click mouseenter',
            ready: true,
            fixed: true,
            delay: 100
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 500
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    show: {
        when: 'mouseenter',
        delay: 1000
    },
    api: {
        onRender: function() {
            this.elements.target.bind('click', this.show);
        }
    }
});
```